# SQL Server convert number to date

Tags: sql-server

How do I convert a numbers in the columns with values like `20160912` into date formats of the form `09/12/2016` and order them by the dates in the date format.

Comment: is that number? or string?

Comment: Best to store them at datetime in the first place.

Comment: It is of datatype number(8) and need to convert to date format.

Comment: Is this `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYYDDMM` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cast` and `convert` built-in functions. Depending on what type is `20160912` you can do following.
A) **`int`**

```
declare @d int=20160912
select convert(varchar(20),convert(date,convert(varchar,@d)),101)
--step by step
declare @dStr varchar(20)
set @dStr = convert(varchar,@d) --'20160912'
-- or = cast(@d as varchar)
declare @dDate date --or datetime
set @dDate = convert(date, @dStr) --2016-09-12 (this is external representation)
--show in MM/dd/yyyy format
select convert(varchar(20), @dDate, 101) --magic 101 for MM/dd/yyyy
--09/12/2016
```

B) **`varchar`** just omit innermost conversion